# Pass the start of the selected month as a parameter to controller function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I have a MVC5 application and I am using Jquery FullCalendar. I have to pass the start of the selected month so as I can fetch data from database based upon which month/year is selected while clicking next and prev button of calendar.
my code is as below:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var calendar = $('#calendar');


       // eventSources: [getCalData()],
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            // calendar.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next ',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
           // eventSources: [
             //   {
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Calendar/GetEvents',
                            // dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                                start: start.unix(),

                            },
                              success: function (doc) {
                                  alert(start);
                                  if (doc == null)
                                  {
                                      alert('no data');
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      alert(doc[0].title);
                                  }
                                  var events = [];
                                  $.each(doc, function (index, event) {
                                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                                  });

                              }
                        });
                    }
            });

            $('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
            var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
           // alert('next is clicked, do something');
            events: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")'
        });

        $('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {
            //alert('prev is clicked, do something');
             @Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")
        });

    });

</script>
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetEvents(double start)
        {

            System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
            dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(start).ToLocalTime();

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            int year, month;

            if (start != 0)
            {
                year = dtDateTime.Year;
                month = dtDateTime.Month; 
            }
//some more code here
}
```

The start date fetched when October is displayed is "27th Sept". As it is the first date shown. But I would like to have the start of the month selected i.e october 1.
[image]

Kindly help on the appropriate javascript function to be used. I have tried this:-
 start: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').visStart but this throws exception as visStart doesnt exists.

Calendar library used is 2.4.0. Script tags used in files are:-

```
 <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of parameter start in events callback, always give the starting day of the calendar. In order to get the current display month, you can use the below code.

```
var _currentdate = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
var _date = new Date(_currentdate .year(), _currentdate .month() - 1, 1); //to fetch events from Oct 1st 2015
```

Comment: I want to fetch in the GetEvents method, Oct 1 instead of Sept 27. And I will have to do this for every new month to fetch desired events from database.

Comment: Once you set the firstDay accordingly, you will get the correct value (Oct 1st) in the start parameter. But if you want to start the calendar with Sep27 but need start value as Oct 1st, you can get the current month from $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').month()

Comment: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').month()  worked..thanks :). if you modify your answer with this, i vl accept it.